Use mathscr and euler together
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mdframed, enumerate}
\usepackage[margin = 4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{euler}

I want to use the mathrsfs package to use its \mathscr{} font but I want to use euler for the rest of my math fonts. I am not sure how to proceed.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Just load mathrsfs after euler.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed, enumerate}
\usepackage[margin = 4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

Text in Garamond $a+b+\mathcal{A}+\mathscr{B}$. Bye.

\end{document}


The reason is that euler tries to define its own version of \mathscr. Changing the loading order solves the problem.
By the way, enumerate is considered obsolete (use enumitem instead, check its documentation); mdframed has been unmaintained for years, tcolorbox is much more powerful.
